# Understand how parallel thread group works in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Can someone help me to understand the difference between consecutive and parallel threads in the following scenario
(scenario 1 )
TestPlan: Run thread groups parallel 
ThreadGroups :4 
No Of threads: 4500 
Ramp-up period : 60
loop count 10

Each threadgroup points to a different endpoint

What I have not understood is that at the end of 60 seconds, how many users will be on parallel test plan, 4500 *4 ?
 60 seconds after starting the test, do I have 4500 on each endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know as it depends on:

1. The number of [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in the Thread Group
2. Application response time

Given you have only 10 iterations it might be the case that first thread will finish its 10 iterations in less than 60 seconds and will be shut down and the last thread will not be yet started. Check out [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected/) article for more details.

If you set loop count in the Thread Group to `forever` and you have 4500 threads in each Thread Group - in 1 minute you will have 4500 * 4 = 18000 virtual users. If you want to keep the number of loops at `10` - you can check how many active users were online at this or that time using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener